# point free procedure composition

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

Suppose I have two procedures `p1` and `p2` on the stack and I want to consume them and leave on the stack a new procedure that combines their effects. I would like a procedure to do this.  This is easy enough if I am always willing to do a little dictionary bookkeeping.  But can I do it without introducing any names? (Note that I want the resulting procedure, not just to execute the combined effects on the current stack.)

Consider for example

```
/compose {<< /f1 4 2 roll /f2 exch >>begin {f1 f2} end}bind def
```

This won't work of course because f1 and f2 will be unknown after `end`.  But this broken code should illustrate what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally possible, and not terribly difficult. You make a new array with each procedure object followed by the executable name `exec`. Then make that array executable.

```
/combine { % {a} {b}  .  {{a} exec {b} exec}
    /exec cvx exch     % {a} exec {b}
    /exec cvx          % {a} exec {b} exec
    4 array astore     % [{a} exec {b} exec]
    cvx                % {{a} exec {b} exec}
} def
```

For a style closer to your original, with named arguments, I would write it like this:

```
% fun1 fun2  compose  proc
/compose { 2 dict begin       % f1 f2
    {f2 f1}{exch def} forall  %
    ({ //f1 exec //f2 exec }) % ({ //f1 exec //f2 exec })
    cvx exec                  % { <f1> exec <f2> exec }
end } def
```

The `//immediate-name` syntax is very powerful. Here I use a code template in a string. When the string is executed `cvx exec` it invokes the scanner upon the contents and it is then that it automatically `load`s all tokens prefixed with double-slash `//`. The comment `<f1>` indicates the contents of the named variable. Just like an `{executable array}` in the program stream is not executed but yields the proc on the stack, `exec`ing a string containing one will also yield the proc on the stack.

For the named arguments style, I make use of a few special rules of postscript: executable arrays are not executed, thus the array of variable names can be written as an executable array and then used as data without any additional hassle. But by using the executable syntax, the contents -- the names -- can be written without the `/`s. So, instead of `[ /f2 /f1 ]` we can write the shorter `{ f2 f1 }`.

The arguments part could also be factored into its own function.

```
/argsbegin { % a r g s _ {n a m e s}  .  -
    dup length dict begin
    {exch def} forall  % currentdict:<</n _  /a s  /m g  /e r  /s a>>
} def

/compose { {f2 f1} argsbegin
    ({//f1 exec //f2 exec}) token pop exch pop %another way to invoke the scanner
end } def
```

Or, to actually put the arguments the right way around, it could be like the following. It's just a little more awkward to simulate a backwards `forall` with a `for` loop.

```
/argsbegin { % a r g s _ {n a m e s}  .  -
    dup length dup dict begin  % a r g s _ {} n
    1 sub -1 0 {  % a r g s _ {} i
        3 2 roll  % a r g s {} i _
        3 copy    % a r g s {} i _ {} i _
        pop       % a r g s {} i _ {} i
        get       % a r g s {} i _ /s
        exch def  % a r g s {} i
        pop       % a r g s {}
    } for         % {}
    pop
} def

/compose { {f1 f2} argsbegin
    ({//f1 exec //f2 exec}) cvx exec
end } def
```

Comment: Nice.  I was trying to figure out a way to use `exec`, but I did not realize I could push the literal name on the stack and then make it executable.  Thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome. I love postscript questions that really get into the programming aspects. I have a more complicated example in my [document formatting engine](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/ibis.ps/blob/0c0aa7d5bd683d21d9814b2b697a85028bcddc81/ibis.ps#L750) from about lines 750 to 850 it defines a function called `addstyle` which performs a composition of *morphisms* (change-state/revert-state function pairs).

Comment: A slightly earlier draft of the same program is [up for review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117320/document-formatting-markup-engine-in-postscript) but it's easier to read on GitHub with line numbers and syntax highlighting.

Comment: Supercool and helpfully commented.  I wish I could contribute to a code review, but I'm a novice.  My only comment on the markup is that if you want to emphasize the user it seems to me that leaning more heavily on HTML and CSS could be useful.  (IViz, tag names,  external style sheet, and the CSS synatx for style.)  Also:
http://www.anastigmatix.net/postscript/Hyphenate.html 
just in case you missed it.  Finally, have you using restructured text as your markup?  It seems you would like your raw documents to be very readable, and the (Python) parsing code is public domain and well tested.

Comment: Very early on I was very impressed by automatic hyphenation. But when I finally read Knuth's papers, he doesn't consider it very central. The paragraph-fitting algorithm is the place to make the most gains first, (according to my interpretation of Knuth.) As for html and css, I devised this code mostly to avoid learning too much of those :) I am sorely tempted to make it more like markdown, though. Be sure to visit [comp.lang.postscript](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.postscript) for postscript discussions without the Q/A format. :)

Comment: Just fyi, I have found restructured text far more expressive than markdown.  It is worth a very serious look if you are considering changes to your markup syntax.
http://zverovich.net/2016/06/16/rst-vs-markdown.html

Comment: So based on what I learned from your answer, I believe that a way to fix the version with explicit names can be handled similarly:
`/compose {<< /f1 4 2 roll /f2 exch >>begin [/f1 load /exec cvx /f2 load /exec cvx] cvx end} def`.  Is that what I should have been doing in that style?

Comment: That will work. But I think it's nicer if you use `//immediately-loaded-names`, so the scanner will do the `load`s. There's another style I like for naming arguments, so I'll incorporate that here, too. `/compose {2 dict begin {f2 f1}{exch def}forall ({//f1 exec //f2 exec}) cvx exec end} def`. (Btw, enjoying the reading about RST, thanks!).